# Como fazer multi upload de imagens no Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Preciso fazer um sistema para gerar galeria de fotos, como fazer multi upload no CodeIgniter?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Se o autor conseguir elaborar melhor o problema, eu voto para reabrir.

Answer (score 2):

Para se realizar múltiplos uploads no Codeigniter você deve utilizar uma biblioteca que proporcione a sua aplicação essa peculiaridade.

Recomendo o [SWFUpload](https://code.google.com/p/swfupload/wiki/v250Beta1)
https://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Já para os *uploads* dos arquivos segue o link da especificação do [framework](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework)
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Ao baixar o **SWFUpload** (SWFUpload v2.2.0.1 Samples.zip), no diretório demos, você encontrará o exemplo com um arquivo upload.php. Neste arquivo é onde serão feitas as alteraçôes para que o mesmo faça o processo de upload utilizando o framework.

**[RECOMENDO]**

Contudo, com o advento do HTML5, o uso de um biblioteca se tornou opcional.

Exemplo de multiplos uploads com [html5](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5)
http://demos.9lessons.info/multiupload/index.php